# Directive declared and exported from core module but not triggering Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I had created a directive in my Core Module folder and added it to declarations and exported in such module. This module is implemented in App Module (The principal module). I use the directive decorator in my index page (This page is declared in another module Page Module) everything is well I don't receive any error but the logic of the directive is not triggering.

I have tried declaring the directive in the Page Module and its working. Also something very curious if remove the directive from the core module it throws the error Cannot determine the module for class HasfunctionalityDirective which is correct

### Directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasfunctionality]'
})
export class HasfunctionalityDirective{


  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { 
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elem.nativeElement, 'color', 'blue');
  }
}
```

### Core Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HasfunctionalityDirective } from './directives/hasfunctionality.directive';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HasfunctionalityDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    HasfunctionalityDirective
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

### App Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Index.html

```
<p appHasfunctionality>
  index works!
</p>
```

In this case the element 'p' should change the color to blue.

As you can see the app module receives all the elements of the core and angular doesn't throw any error but the logic is not triggering.

Comment: Can you please try the following instead `el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'` to set the color to "blue".

Comment: Hi Alexander, already tried that, the code i showing up work's IF i declare the directive directly in the pages module.  I think this is something of lazy load?

Comment: Did you name templateUrl for AppComponent as index.html? Or do you want that your directive works for index.html?

Comment: Hi yurzui, no the index.html is created in Page Module level.

Comment: You have to import CoreModule in the module where the component is declared in which template you're trying to use that directive

Comment: Yurzui the purpose of declaring the core module in the app module is for sharing all the directives, guards, services etc to the entire application. in the same component (index) i'm using the services declared in the core module and it's working without a problem

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to my problem, I was declaring the module on the top layer (main), instead of that I moved to the pages module because I realize this is the only place is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a refence to the element in afterviewinit. try this

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2,  AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHasfunctionality]'
})
export class HasfunctionalityDirective implements AfterViewInit {


  constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.elem.nativeElement, 'color', 'blue');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi jcuypers, i tried with oninit, afterviewinit and the result is the same

Comment: weird, this is basically the same:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jv9szt?embed=1&file=src/app/my-custom-directive.directive.ts .   BTW i see nowhere an import for BrowserModule. is it there?

Comment: Yes is the same but I'm using layers in me app as mentioned in the problem, give me time and I'll upload a stackbkitz with the architecture

Comment: For sure the commonmodule. Browsermodule, etc needs to be loaded at app level for any basic angular stuff towork and thid too

Comment: @jcuypers i got some issues here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56076337/8662236
Thanks